# Upgrading / Updating repository problem related to Opera

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, opera

When I try `apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com/opera stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B8EC3BAABDC4346
E: The repository 'http://deb.opera.com/opera stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This also blocks me from upgrading to 20.04. I have already uninstalled Opera; did not use it much anyway.

Comment: Just remove it from your software sources. Open the search applications, type software, click on the one that says software and updates, find the offending repository, untick it, click okay, type your password when asked, and you should be all set.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Now I'm stuck on something else. ;-
)

Comment: LOL The rules are one question per post, so you'll need to make a new one. Anyhow, my response/the fix isn't really worthy of answer status. I'm sure it's a duplicate of something and it's a pretty trivial fix. I suppose I could write it up with screenshots, but I don't think that's really required for this.